# RegEx - How to find all App\Model and not App\Something\Model

Tags: regex, laravel, model

Upgrading from Laravel 6 to 8. I want to replace all `App\Model`s to `App\Models\Model` and of course I don't want to replace `App\Something\Class` nor `App\Something\SomethingElse\Class`. How can I achieve this using RegEx?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can not achieve this except with the help of IDE like phpstorm.

Comment: How can I do it with PhpStorm?

Comment: To be honest I'm not a regex expert but I tried it and it worked for me. First, move all your models inside the `Models` directory then push `CTRL+SHIFT-R` and select the `regex` option from the top right. 

Now for models which are in the nested directories inside the `Models` 

Replace `App\\+(?!Models)` With `App\\Models\\ `

For models that are inside the root of the `Models`  directory

Replace `App;` with `App\\Models;`

Hope it helps...

Comment: Also, make sure the `Directory` tab is selected on the replacement panel. Not `In Project` nor `Module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to replace references and don't need to move the files, then the following regex should work (**note I am no regex wizard so there is likely a better method**).

```
^App\\([\w]+;)$
```

You can then use the capture groups `()` to replace and insert your new pathing:

```
App\Models\\$1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I wanted.